# why php form builder class is not running?

Tags: php, javascript, oop, tinymce, ckeditor

I want to use [php form builder class](http://www.imavex.com/pfbc2.x-php5/index.php#project-overview). But I can't run this class.
Im using as below(from [example page](http://www.imavex.com/pfbc2.x-php5/examples/elements.php)):

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'PFBC/Form.php';
$form = new Form("webeditors", 650);
$form->addElement(new Element_Hidden("form", "webeditors"));
$form->addElement(new Element_TinyMCE("TinyMCE:", "TinyMCE"));
$form->addElement(new Element_CKEditor("CKEditor:", "CKEditor"));
$form->addElement(new Element_Button);
$form->render();
?>
```

Result of above codes:

[HTML codes](http://ideone.com/uhgQE).

[image]

But it must be as below:

[image]

PHP Designer 7 Result:

[image]

Output of Javascript Error Console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/PFBC/Resources/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/PFBC/Resources/ckeditor/ckeditor.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
```

Where is the problem. I can't understand.

Meantime, I'm using AppServ AppServ 2.5.10

Somebody says you need to download tinymce and ckeditor and optimize for your project. But already **pfbc** has all.

[image]

Comment: You should be seeing JavaScript errors in your console. What are they?

Comment: I thought this was PHP not Java.

Comment: @redelman431: JavaScript not Java. And you can see it differently depending on your browser. In Google Chrome, press CTRL+SHIFT+J.

Comment: @Truth okey. Everything was added.

Comment: @Birlikisgu: And here you go, the errors you're receiving explain it all pretty well. The files don't exist where they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the generated HTML output and any errors from your JavaScript console. My guess is that you don't have the required JavaScript/CSS files included properly in your page or they are not configured to target the desired elements.

Comment: The configuration set up files `tiny_mce.js` and `ckeditor.js` were not found in the desired folder of your server. You'll either have to download TinyMCE and CKEditor and extract them to these folders or reconfigure your page and have them point to the correct location on your server.

Comment: pfbc has all already. please look first message again. And this problem not for only tinymce and ckeditor. If you look to code result, you can see submit button. Submit button is not running. In a sense hasn't got any value.

Comment: Not having worked with PFBC, my only guess is that the library is misconfigured. Your browser is not able to fetch the required files in order to display the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Please try manually setting the resourcesPath Form property (see example below) via the configure method.

$form->configure(array(
    "resourcesPath" => "localhost/bigbeng/classes/PFBC/Resources"
));

Alternately, you can edit PFBC/Form.php and set the property in the Form class constructor so you don't have to manually set it for each form.